# Why is Poe Dameron so shocked in the First Order star destroyer hangar?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, first-order, poe-dameron

When Poe Dameron is first taken off the shuttle into the hangar of the First Order ship Finalizer, he stops and looks around with a very shocked expression.

Poe knows intimate details of the TIE fighter, and probably a star destroyer based on his knowledge of the cannons when he escapes. At all other times Poe is very calm and collected so even if this was his first time inside a star destroyer he seems particularly unprepared for what he sees.

So, why is he so shocked?

Comment: Out-of-Universe speaking: this is the kind of details that the prequels missed, the moment when a character is dazzled by a place, showing that there's magnitude, that he is standing in an amazing place, and we as an audience get excited too. The Original Trilogy had several of those moments, like the immortal "That's no moon"... It shows that the character has feelings, and you believe that one is not standing in front of a blue screen. It seems that the new movies are in the right direction... which would be away from the prequels... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) offers the following information

> INT. STAR DESTROYER HANGAR - NIGHT
>
> Poe, shackled, is ushered from the transport through the hangar. **He is
>   awed by the imposing space.**
>
> **POE:** *All right. All right!*

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) concurs, stating that it's "*enormous and impressive*".

> The shackles that Poe had worn on the troop transport were removed as soon as he and his captors disembarked. Aboard the Star Destroyer, there was no reason to physically restrain the prisoner. Apparently enjoying themselves, or perhaps merely impatient to get out of their armor, his escort chivvied him along with what he considered to be unnecessary roughness. Not that stormtroopers of any ilk were noted for their individual diplomacy. Considering whom he had tried to shoot, he knew he ought to consider himself fortunate that they had brought him aboard still attached to all his important appendages.
>   A physical state of being, he knew, that could be altered at any moment.
>   **On the other side of the enormous and impressive receiving bay, other troopers were filing out, grateful that more of their number had not been lost on the expedition and looking forward to some rest and food.**

You may wish to note that this Star Destroyer is nearly twice the size of a *standard* Imperial Star Destroyer and the receiving bay is apparently similarly scaled upward. Even if Poe was familiar with Star Destroyers, the Finalizer is simply bigger and more impressive.

Comment: I wonder how "night" on a Star Destroyer differs from "day"...

Comment: @MiloPrice - They dim the lights and crank up the *smooth jazz*.